# Is there an analytic function that satisifes this?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there an analytic function of two complex variables that satisfies this? Or a proof to say otherwise?

$$f(z,w) =0 \implies z=0 \land w=0$$

I can only find a non-analytic function $f(z,w)=|z|^2+|w|^2$.

Obviously $f(z,w)=z^2+w^2$ won't work since $f(1,i)=0$.

Comment: $1/f$ would be analytic on $\mathbb C^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ but any such function extends to be analytic on $\mathbb C^2$, by Hartogs.

Comment: Thanks. Is that a proof that no such function exists?

Comment: Yes. Philosophically: The vanishing locus of a holomorphic section is codimension 1.